# Apache Spark Shuffle Writes but no Shuffle Reads

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

Again a spark shuffle question...

I have a single node setup on a fairly big instance (160GB RAM, 40 cores). I do want to train ~250 models of ALS with different parameters (based on the same data frame).

After multiple days of looking into issues with disk I/O I found this conversation: http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/Eliminating-shuffle-write-and-spill-disk-IO-reads-writes-in-Spark-td16955.html

I did like they said and pointed my `spark.local.dir` to a RAM disk. I think its doing the job, all cores are now nicely used. Good!

However, I do see something I can't understand in the executors tab:

[image: Executor metrics screenshot]

It looks like there is only Shuffle writing but no reading. Simple question: Why? Is it necessary? And if not: How could I avoid that?

Main block of the execution:

```
    val modelsAndResults =  parameters.par.map( e => {
        var auc = 0d 

        splits.zipWithIndex.foreach { case ((training, validation), splitIndex) => 
                val trainingDataset = spark.createDataFrame(training, schema).cache()
                val validationDataset = spark.createDataFrame(validation, schema).cache()

                val als = baseALS.copy(ParamMap(
                    baseALS.rank -> e._2,
                    baseALS.maxIter -> e._1,
                    baseALS.alpha -> e._4,
                    baseALS.regParam -> e._5,
                    baseALS.nonnegative -> e._6));

                //println(s"$e evaluating $splitIndex ...")
                val localAUC = new BinaryClassificationEvaluator().evaluate(
                    validationDataset
                        .join(als.fit(trainingDataset).transform(validationDataset.drop("time")), Seq("user","article"))
                        .withColumn("label", when($"time" >= e._2, 1d).otherwise(0d)).drop("time")
                        .withColumn("rawPrediction", $"prediction".cast(DoubleType))
                        .select("label","rawPrediction"))
                auc += localAUC

                trainingDataset.unpersist()
                validationDataset.unpersist()

                //println(s"$e evaluating $splitIndex ... localAUC: $localAUC")
            }

        val finalAUC = auc / splits.size

        val csv = CSVWriter.open("cf_gridsearch_results_12345.csv", append = true)
        csv.writeRow(List(e._1,e._2,e._3,e._4,e._5,e._6,finalAUC))
        csv.close()

        println((e._1,e._2,e._3,e._4,e._5,e._6,finalAUC))

        (e._1,e._2,e._3,e._4,e._5,e._6,finalAUC)
})
```

Comment: Please provide code snippet where main actions happens (like collect, action with Key)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shuffling means the data exchange among multiple Spark stages. Shuffle write appears at the end of stages when all data serialized from all executors before transmition. Shuffle read take place at the beginning of stages gathering data from all executors. In order to get the whole picture with  shuffle read/write you have to run in cluster mode. In that case the shuffle read&writes will be triggered

**EDIT**

In your case you are running in one instance with one executor it means there no need to bring partitions from other executors so there won't be shuffle reads. Regarding shuffle writes it appears during the save operation of the dataframe by calling cache.

Comment: The question is why does it write several GBs but never reads a single bit?

Comment: E.g spark dataset (RDD) consists of partitions. Partitions refer to part of data as lines, rows.  All of them during tasks execution are split among executors. Some actions require shuffle of partitions between executors (e.g grouping rows with same key).

Comment: Probably I miss the point  @FaigB but how does it explain the writes without reads? Also I have only one executor (single node)

Comment: @gapvision added explanation about why shuffle read didn't take place